# Grails ORM one to many not working as expected

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two simple tables in my db

```
class A{
    String a_1
    String a_2
    static hasMany = [b:B]
}

class B{
    String b_1
    static belongsTo = [a:A]
}
```

and here is my controller

```
def getById = {
    def aInstance = A.get(1)
    render aInstance as JSON
}
```

and here is what i get

```
{"class":"com.A","id":1,"a_1":"a","a_2":"2","b":[{"class":"B","id":2},{"class":"B","id":1}]}
```

as per this documentation http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany i thought i also will get b_1 parameter for my B class, but instead i just got ids

Is there any settings that i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to fetch the `b` collection eagerly like this:

```
class A{
    String a_1
    String a_2
    static hasMany = [b:B]
    static fetchMode = [b: 'eager']
}
```

Comment: hmm,
maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625641/selective-deep-rendering-of-hasmany-relationships-in-grails

Comment: wow, it's working. thanks. but i still don't get it, is the problem coming from json class itself? it can't serialize another properties than id?