# Getting restful domain object without hasMany relationships

Tags: grails

We're writing an json API with grails. Here is a simplify example with the domains and controller:

```
class Employee {
    String name
    Section section
}

class Section {
    static hasMany = [employees: Employee]
    String name
}


@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class SectionController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
    static responseFormats = ['json']

    def index() {
        request.withFormat {
            json {
                respond Section.list()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the `Section` list without employees, something like:

```
[
  {"class":"Section","id":1,"name":"A"},
  {"class":"Section","id":2,"name":"B"},
  {"class":"Section","id":3,"name":"C"},
  {"class":"Section","id":4,"name":"D"},
  {"class":"Section","id":5,"name":"F"}
]
```

But the controller returns:

```
[
  {"class":"Section","id":1,"name":"A","employees":[{"class":"Employee","id":1},{"class":"Employee","id":2},{"class":"Employee","id":3}]},
  {"class":"Section","id":2,"name":"B","employees":[{"class":"Employee","id":4},{"class":"Employee","id":5},{"class":"Employee","id":6},{"class":"Employee","id":7}]},
  {"class":"Section","id":3,"name":"C","employees":[{"class":"Employee","id":8},{"class":"Employee","id":9},{"class":"Employee","id":10}]},
  {"class":"Section","id":4,"name":"D","employees":[{"class":"Employee","id":11}]}
]
```

When I delete the `hasMany` relationship, I get what I want, however, I need the relationship to do complex `Criteria` and `hql` queries

How can I do to return data without `hasMany` relationship.

Thanks.

Comment: You can define custom JSON marshaller. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625641/selective-deep-rendering-of-hasmany-relationships-in-grails

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I had hope. Thank you.